# Python (merge) create brand choice/purchase dataset

Tags: python, pandas, merge, data-cleaning

I am trying to create a choice model dataset from multiple csv (Think of whether individuals buy a brand of a product at a given price).

A small representation of my data:

```
import pandas as pd

d1 = {'Product': [1,1,2,2,3], 'Price': [25, 25, 22, 22,35], 'Buyer ID': ['A','B','C','D','E']}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(d1)
```

Where df1 contains information relating to products that a buyer considered purchasing. Note that all three products (1,2 &3) are available to the consumer when they are making their purchase decision.

```
d2 = {'Buyer Num': ['A','B','E'], 'Product': [1,1,3,], 'Purchase Decision': ['Yes','Yes','Yes']}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(d2)
```

df2 contains information on which product a consumer finally purchased. Consumers A, B and E bought products 1,1 & 3 respectively.

I tried merging the two datasets using outer and inner join. For eg:

```
df3 = df1.merge(df2,left_on='Buyer ID', right_on='Buyer Num', how='outer')
```

What I get from an outer join is :

```
   Buyer ID  Price  Product_x Buyer Num  Product_y Purchase Decision
     A        25          1         A        1.0               Yes
     B        25          1         B        1.0               Yes
     C        22          2       NaN        NaN               NaN
     D        22          2       NaN        NaN               NaN
     E        35          3         E        3.0               Yes
```

However what I optimally want is something like this-

```
Buyer ID    Price   Product  Purchase Decision
A             25        1      Yes
B             25        1      Yes
C             25        1      No
D             25        1      No
E             25        1      No
A             22        2      No
B             22        2      No
C             22        2      No
D             22        2      No
E             22        2      No
A             35        3      No
B             35        3      No
C             35        3      No
D             35        3      No
E             35        3      Yes
```

Could someone tell me to how to do this on Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
from itertools import product

# Outer merge and drop the unwanted column
df = pd.merge(df1, df2, left_on=['Buyer ID', 'Product'], right_on=['Buyer Num', 'Product'], 
              how='outer').drop('Buyer Num', axis=1)

# Generate cartesian product of 'Buyer ID' & 'Price' after retrieving unique values 
midx = product(df1['Buyer ID'].unique(), df1['Price'].unique())
# Set the earlier columns as index and reindex based on the obtained cartesian product values
d = df.set_index(['Buyer ID', 'Price']).reindex(midx)
# Fill Nans in 'Product' with the finite value in each sub-group of level 1 grouped index
d['Product'].fillna(d.groupby(level='Price')['Product'].transform('first'), inplace=True)
# Fill the remaining Nans with "No"
d.fillna('No').sort_values('Product').reset_index()
```

[image]

Comment: Much appreciated. Thanks a lot.